# How to load more data using the Laravel in tabular form

Tags: datatables, laravel-5.3

**I have daily data of 500 rows nearly and I have to show in tabular form the data for 4 years. I am using Laravel and putting the output in Datatable.**
The data hangs itself in the ajax data itself. 
How to proceed in this, so I can show data in some chunks(pagination) easily? **Please help by giving some example link.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally use laravel datatable for this type of task. It's straight forward and saves you from stress. https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

```
 public  static function user_list(){

        $users = User::select(['id','name', 'email','created_at'])->with('profile')->get();
        return Datatables::of($users)

            ->addColumn('roles', function ($users){
                return $users->roles->values()->implode('name',',');
            })
            ->addColumn('Phone', function ($users){

                   return $users->phone;
               }
            })

            ->addColumn('Sex', function ($users){
                return $users->sex
            })
            ->addColumn('Edit', function ($users){
            return $users->id;
            })
            ->addColumn('Delete', function ($users){
                return $users->id;
            })



            ->make();

    }
```

And in my view

```
 <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({
                        processing: true,
                        serverSide: true,
                        ajax: '{!! url('user/datatable/list') !!}',
                        "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, 500, 1000, -1], [50, 100, 500, 1000, "All"]],

                        dom: 'Bfrtip',
                        buttons: [
                             'excel', 'pdf', 'print',
                            'copyHtml5',
                            'excelHtml5',
                            'csvHtml5',
                            'pdfHtml5',
                            'colvis'
                        ],
                        'columnDefs': [{
                            'targets': 0,
                            'searchable': false,
                            'orderable': false,
                            'className': 'dt-body-center',
                });

            </script>
```